# Delete all user data in UIViewController's after logout

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

When I login to my app, my app does push the ViewController `XYZMainViewController`, `XYZMainViewController` `viewWillAppear:animated` call method that makes a request to my API to retrieve the authenticated user data, at this time I update the text of a label to show the user name. When I logout the app, it returns me to the login ViewController, when I do login again with another user, XYZMainViewController label text contains the name of the previous user, without updating the label text.

**XYZMainViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [self homeProfile];
}

- (void)homeProfile
{
    [NXOAuth2Request performMethod:@"GET"
                        onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://{url}/users/userinfo"]
                   usingParameters:nil
                       withAccount:[XYZCommonFunctions user]
               sendProgressHandler:nil
               responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){
                   NSDictionary *parsedData = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error] objectForKey:@"data"];
                   _user = [parsedData objectForKey:@"user"];
                   [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!", [_user objectForKey:@"username"]]];
               }];

}

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    XYZAppDelegate* appDelegate = (XYZAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate logout];
}
```

**XYZAppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)login
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *identifier = [prefs stringForKey:@"accountidentifier"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    NSString *viewIdentifier = @"WelcomeView";
    if(identifier != nil){
        NXOAuth2Account *account = [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accountWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if(account != nil) {
            viewIdentifier = @"MainView";
        }
        UIViewController *controller = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: viewIdentifier];
        [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
        return;
    }
}

- (void)logout
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs removeObjectForKey:@"accountidentifier"];
    [prefs synchronize];
    for (NXOAuth2Account *a in [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accounts] ){
        [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] removeAccount:a];
    }
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I need to reinitialize all data in `XYZMainViewController`.

Thank you.

Comment: after successful login of user u should clear the label(username) before passing onto next view(VC)

Answer (score 0):

Look like problem is related to fetching JSON Object. It is possible that everytime you have send same user to fetch user data. You are not using NSUserdefault object to display name, you are using value, which is return by JSON Object. According to me cause of error is "withAccount:[XYZCommonFunctions user]" line.

Comment: "withAccount: [XYZCommonFunctions user]" line is just a method to retrieve the OAuth access_token to make requests to the API. NSUserDefaults only used to find the ID of the account used to make these requests. Thank you nadim.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest, instead of using

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
```

you can use

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

so that your login action performed only when your LoginController loads,instead when LoginController appear.

New viewwillAppear look as given below -

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [self.label setText:@""];
}
```

and ViewDidLoad -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self homeProfile];
}
```

Also check your json response, whether you are getting response success or error.According to response need to handle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello vicky, that does not work, I've tried but still as before, now I followed what you said and I handle request errors. Thank you.